# randomize a data.frame based on a column and keeping proportions

Tags: r, permutation

I have a data.frame that looks like this (my real data.frame is bigger but the structure is similar):

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(rep('A', 5), rep('B', 5), rep('C',5)), Score=c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0))
```

And I would like to obtain several *randomized* data.frames (e.g 100) where column *Score* is randomized and column *ID* remains the same, but I need to keep the same number of *zeros* and *ones* in `df$Score.

I've tried with:

```
df1 <- transform(df, Score=ave(Score, ID, FUN=function(b) sample(b, replace=T)))
```

but the proportions of `0s` and `1s` are not kept always,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the 0-1 proportion within `ID`s, set `replace=F` (which is by default):

```
df1 <- transform(df, Score=ave(Score, ID, FUN=function(b) sample(b, replace=F)))
```

If you want to keep the overall 0-1 porportion, you can simply do this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=df$ID, Score=sample(df$Score))
```